# Problem with installing a Laravel package using composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-passport, guzzle

I want to using a package in my project.

Composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
    "hekmatinasser/verta": "^1.11",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
    "laravel/passport": "^9.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.3",
    "pishran/zarinpal": "^2.2"
},
```

My target package to install :

```
composer require ipecompany/smsirlaravel
```

Problem : When I try this on composer, I see follwing error

```
Problem 1
- ipecompany/smsirlaravel[v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.7] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 7.2
.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires ipecompany/smsirlaravel ^1.0 -> satisfiable by ipecompany/smsirlaravel[v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.7].
```

I tried :

`composer require ipecompany/smsirlaravel -W`

But the main problem is `Laravel Passport` maybe because of following error :

```
  Problem 1
    - laravel/passport is locked to version v9.3.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/passport v9.3.2 requires laminas/laminas-diactoros ^2.2 -> found laminas/laminas-diactoros[2.2.0, ..., 2.6.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
```

I tried to install `laminas/laminas-diactoros ^2.2` but I got another error

```
problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laminas/laminas-diactoros 2.2, found laminas/laminas-diactoros[2.2.0] but it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/passport is locked to version v9.3.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/passport v9.3.2 requires laminas/laminas-diactoros ^2.2 -> found laminas/laminas-diactoros[2.2.0, ..., 2.6.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
```

Any body can help me to install this package? TNX

Answer (score 1):

As written in the first error message: `ipecompany/smsirlaravel` requires v6 of Guzzle, but currently v7 is installed. You should use a different version constraint for Guzzle first: change  `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1"` to  `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1"`. Afterwards, run `composer update guzzlehttp/guzzle` such that Guzzle v6 is installed.

Afterwards, running `composer require ipecompany/smsirlaravel` should work